# SQL many-to-many count sum

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

```
id_user id_user2
1      54
1      53
1      53
1      54
1      54
1      55
2      23
2      23
2      20
2      21
2      25
2      25
```

And i would like to count, how many each of `id_user` have relationship with `id_user2`. Output should be:

```
id_user id_user2    result
1       54          3
1       53          2
1       55          1
2       23          2
2       20          1
2       21          1
2       25          2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `group by` clause

```
select id_user,id_user2, count(1) as result
from userstab
group by id_user,id_user2
```

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
select id_user,id_user2,count(id_user2) as result
from TABLE_NAME group by id_user2
```